# How to compute N th Values for the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I have 3 variables X, Y, Z

> $X_0=3$.
>
> $Y_0=1$.
>
> $Z_0=0$.
>
> $X_n=X_{n-1} + 3 * Z_{n_-1}$.
>
> $Y_n=X_{n-1} + 2 * Z_{n_-1}$.
>
> $Z_n= 5* Y_{n-1} $.

I have tried alot to get a series or pattern for the nth X, Y or Z. But not able to.
I tried getting numbers till 10th elements but i cannot find a pattern here.

> 1- 3,3,5
>
> 2- 18,13,15
>
> 3- 63,48,65
>
> 4- 258,193,240
>
> 5- 978,738,965
>
> 6- 3873,2908,3690
>
> 7- 14943,11253,14540
>
> 8- 58563,44023,56265
>
> 9- 227358,171093,220115

Could someone Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: write the recurrence in matrix form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x_n \\ y_n \\ z_n \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 5 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{n-1} \\ y_{n-1} \\ z_{n-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
which we can abbreviate as $v_n = M v_{n-1}$. Then
$$v_n = M^n v_0$$
If you can express $M = PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal, then $M^n = PD^nP^{-1}$, where $D^n$ is easy to compute.

The diagonalization procedure amounts to finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$. The diagonal elements of $D$ will be the eigenvalues of $M$, and the columns of $P$ will be the corresponding eigenvectors. The procedure succeeds as long as there is a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors.

I carried out the calculation for your matrix using Matlab and found that $M$ is indeed diagonalizable, but the numbers aren't nice:

$$D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
         -2.34996671764659     &                    0      &                   0 \\
                         0     &   -0.546110732079137       &                  0 \\
                         0      &                   0       &   3.89607744972573 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        -0.629646469892229   &     0.887784764389145       &  0.632739387720272 \\
        -0.330451492337396    &    0.0499732661162395     &    0.475960995779856 \\
         0.703098239340878    &    -0.457537850666135    &     0.610820757443314 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
It may appear that this doesn't simplify things at all, because to compute $PD^nP^{-1}$ requires multiplying three matrices for each $n$. But we can exploit the fact that $D$ is diagonal to obtain an equivalent form which is much simpler to compute.

To see this, let $p_1, p_2, p_3$ denote the column vectors of $P$, and let $q_1^T, q_2^T, q_3^T$ denote the row vectors of $P^{-1}$. Let $d_1, d_2, d_3$ be the diagonal elements of $D$. Then
$$\begin{align}
PD^nP^{-1} &= 
\begin{pmatrix}p_1 & p_2 & p_3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}d_1^n & 0 & 0 \\
0 & d_2^n & 0 \\
0 & 0 & d_3^n \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1^T \\ q_2^T \\ q_3^T
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= d_1^n(p_1 q_1^T) + d_2^n (p_2 q_2^T) + d_3^n (p_3 q_3^T)\\
\end{align}$$
Note that each $(p_i q_i^T)$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix that does not depend on $n$, so you only need to compute it once. The $d_i^n$ are just scalars. So this expression is a sum of matrices rather than a product.

For your problem, assuming you want $v_0 = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 3 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$ (not 3,3,5 as in your calculation), the solution is
$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_n \\ y_n \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}
&= d_1^n(p_1 q_1^T)v_0  + d_2^n (p_2 q_2^T)v_0 + d_3^n (p_3 q_3^T)v_0 \\
&= (-2.34996671764659)^n
\begin{pmatrix}
         0.924590698768491 \\
         0.485244324901271 \\
         -1.03244935610668 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&+ (-0.546110732079137)^n
\begin{pmatrix}
         -1.37022605593431 \\
       -0.0771298112777657 \\
         0.706173736818166 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&+ (3.89607744972573)^n
\begin{pmatrix}
          3.44563535716581 \\
          2.59188548637649 \\
          3.32627561928852 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
I suspect that's about as simplified as it's going to get.

Comment: I am sorry the v0 values are 3,1,0. Not 3 3 5, that is v1.
Aplogies, I had edited this but dont know how it got missed.